# Discord.py API: loop does not break when user inputs "bingo"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
elif "!bingo" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Here's your miniature Bingo sequence")
        shuffled = shuffle(bingo)
        await message.channel.send(bingo[0:3])
        await message.channel.send(bingo[3:6])
        await message.channel.send(bingo[6:9])
        channel = message.channel
        while userinput != "bingo":
            await message.channel.send("Type anything to move on, or type bingo to end!")
            def check(m):
                return m.channel == channel
                userinput[0](str(m.content))
            if message.author == client.user:
                return
            else:
                msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
                if str(userinput) == "bingo":
                    break
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(random.randint(1,9))
```

The function is supposed to break when you input bingo, but for some reason the userinput string doesn't have any value. It is defined earlier on in the code, so it's not the cause of the problem.

Please help thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the solution. Both comments didn't solve the issue entirely (though the second comment helped me find a problem which was present), the loop was fine but the problem was that you cannot compare ```str(userinput)``` to a string because the ```userinput``` variable is a list. A very amateur mistake. Anyways, the if statement was modified to ```if "bingo" in userinput:```. Everything else was kept the same. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You can self answer and accept your question, this helps others to find this answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == channel
        userinput[0](str(m.content))
```

The second part is never executed as you always return with the first statement.
So `userinput` is never set to `m.content` as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There was a problem in this statement since it didn't perform the check. However there was a more glaring issue that ```userinput``` was unable to be compared. I used an ```in``` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple answer:

```
if str(userinput) == "bingo":
    return
```

`break` is suppossed to be used to exit a function. And it doesn't work that well at it's designed job anyway.

Sorry if I am wrong, I am pretty new to discord.py, but I am not new to Python. Discord.py may be changing something to do with Python. If this doesn't work, sadly, I probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: I think the break is used to break out of the while loop and not the function. Using a return at this point alters the behavior as no code after the while loop in this function will be executed.

Comment: Well, as I said before, `break` isn't very reliable.

Comment: What makes you think that? I have never heard of any case where break did not work as it should. Do you have any proof or example? See the Python [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=break#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for a description of what break should do: "The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop."

Comment: In my experience, `break` is failing to exit the program.

Comment: What do you mean by exit the program? Neither return nor break exit a program. Return exits a function and break exits a loop or switch/case...